# Sorry something went wrong error while try to create new list view

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Recently i tried to open List settings page in SharePoint 2013 but it is throwing Sorry some thing went wrong- unexpected error for a specific list,For remaining lists its working fine.

I tried to crate new list view it has showing Web part error. Then onwords i'm unable to create new views and modify views as well as List settings page also throwing error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG52a.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWviy.png

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any lookup columns on that list?
this error could be thrown for several reasons,
1-a list is created from a saved template, if yes then make sure any lookup column you got in there is linked correctly else you need to re-link that column.
2-a list got a lookup columns inside it and the target list has been deleted then you need 
to re-link your lookup column to a different list or delete that lookup column from it.
if nothing of the above try to post here a snapshot of your columns for a better inspection.